# Django bootstrapform render field and lable separate in template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I am using Django 2.0.4 with `bootstrapform` https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form . I would like to render my field and label separately in my template.

Currently I can render the field using:

```
{% load bootstrap %}

{{ form.fieldname|bootstrap }}
```

I would to find a way to separate the render of the label from the field so that I can insert text next to the label for selecting tool-tip. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction to achieve this? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following : This [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html) provides more info

```
{{ form.field_name }} will render the field

{{ form.field_name.label }} will render the label

{{ form.field_name.id_for_label }} the ID
```

Comment: Hi Lemayzeur, this only works without the |bootstrap tag. If I go down this route I will need to apply additional styling for the fields I apply this method. i was hoping to achieve this using the |bootstrap tag.

Comment: `{{ form|bootstrap }}`
# or use with individual field
`{{ form.<field name>|bootstrap }}` - To output individual fields

Comment: Yes that is what I have already. I'm trying to see if it is possible to separate the field_name from the field>name.label when still using the |bootstrap tag